How to display a 3.5 TFT LCD with rpi3 using Busybox/Linux built with Buildroot?
I'm trying to display a 3.5 TFT LCD on rpi3 (Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2 - Raspberry Pi 2015) built with buildroot+busybox, but sources like this repo from lcdwiki uses debian-based distro tooling for the setup since Raspbian/Raspberry OS is the most used. I am also using chroot and qemu-user-static (ARM) to inspect the filesystem, edit files and run programs. I borrowed the rpi3 for this and neither I nor the owner have the buildroot configuration source. Can someone point me to what is normally done in these cases?
I've tried to edit some config files. Maybe the /dev management option "Dynamic using devmpfs+mdev" from the buildroot manual could work?
I've tried to understand the boot process order for this case using busybox init instead of a debian-based with systemd and this was my conclusion:



pcb power (ARM11 is disabled )




-> SoC GPU loads first-stage bootloader bootcode.bin into cache L2 and exec




-> bootcode.bin initializes SDRAM and loads the second-stage bootloader start.elf to the external RAM and exec




-> start.elf configures hardware based on config.txt, loads kernel image into kernel.img, read kernel command line arguments from cmdline.txt




-> inits Linux, calling busybox init




-> reads /etc/inittab, which reads the /etc/mdev.conf




-> starts /etc/init.d/rcS"



PS: I edited the post with additional info, but basically it don't have x11 yet. I'm trying to at least get the TTY. Before my edit, /etc/inittab had getty in a serial port using ttyACM0, and it also could connect to a generic video projector. Then I've edited this line to use tty1 so it could display the LCD, which I think that maps to /dev/tty1?
--- Edit: Additional Info ---
The output of /cat/os-release:
/ # cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Buildroot
VERSION=2018.08-gd14bfd8be1
ID=buildroot
VERSION_ID=2018.08
PRETTY_NAME="Buildroot 2018.08"
/ #

The contents of /etc/inittab:
# /etc/inittab
#
# Copyright (C) 2001 Erik Andersen <andersen@codepoet.org>
#
# Note: BusyBox init doesn't support runlevels.  The runlevels field is
# completely ignored by BusyBox init. If you want runlevels, use
# sysvinit.
#
# Format for each entry: <id>:<runlevels>:<action>:<process>
#
# id        == tty to run on, or empty for /dev/console
# runlevels == ignored
# action    == one of sysinit, respawn, askfirst, wait, and once
# process   == program to run

# Startup the system
::sysinit:/bin/mount -t proc proc /proc
::sysinit:/bin/mount -o remount,rw /
::sysinit:/bin/mkdir -p /dev/pts /dev/shm
::sysinit:/bin/mount -a
::sysinit:/sbin/swapon -a
null::sysinit:/bin/ln -sf /proc/self/fd /dev/fd
null::sysinit:/bin/ln -sf /proc/self/fd/0 /dev/stdin
null::sysinit:/bin/ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /dev/stdout
null::sysinit:/bin/ln -sf /proc/self/fd/2 /dev/stderr
::sysinit:/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
# now run any rc scripts
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# Put a getty on the serial port
tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  tty1 0 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL

# Stuff to do for the 3-finger salute
#::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot

# Stuff to do before rebooting
::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcK
::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r 

For the chroot with qemu-user-static and binfmt_misc, I'm doing:

mount the target root filesystem that is placed on a sdCard
mount temporary filesystems (tmpfs) and utilities such as the Ftrace subsystem to do tracing early at the boot.
The script:

up() {
# mount device with udisksctl (udev)
udisksctl mount -b "$device"

# on target rootfs, bind mount local host rootfs
# pseudo-filesystems in the chroot target rootfs
for f in 'dev' 'dev/pts' 'proc' 'sys' 'run'; do
   sudo mount --bind "/$f" "/run/media/$USER/$uuid/$f";
done

# bind mount debug and trace pseudo-filesystems
sudo mount -t tracefs tracefs "/run/media/$USER/$uuid/sys/kernel/tracing/"
sudo mount -t debugfs debufs "/run/media/$USER/$uuid/sys/kernel/debug/"
}

down() {

# unmount the bind mount debug and trace pseudo-filesystems in reverse order
sudo umount "/run/media/$USER/$uuid/sys/kernel/debug/"
sudo umount "/run/media/$USER/$uuid/sys/kernel/tracing/"

# unmount remaining pseudo-filesystems in reverse order
for f in 'run' 'sys' 'proc' 'dev/pts' 'dev'; do
    sudo umount "/run/media/$USER/$uuid/$f";
done

# umount device with udisksctl (udev)
udisksctl unmount -b "$device"
}


copy /bin/qemu-arm-static to the target rootfs /bin/
cd to target rootfs and sudo chroot . /bin/sh
# source /etc/profile


Thanks for the answer :). I edited the post with remaining info, but basically it don't have x11 yet, I'm trying to at least get the TTY. Before my edit, /etc/inittab had getty in a serial port using ttyACM0, and it also could connect to a generic video projector. I also tried with ttyUSB0, then finally I've edited this line to use tty1, trying to display the LCD, which I think that maps to /dev/tty1? The full line is: tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  tty1 0 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL

You don't need X11.  That is the idea behind /dev/fb0.  It is like 'DOS mode'.  Typically an LCD is mapped as a framebuffer.  https://docs.kernel.org/fb/fbcon.html  It is possible that it is a serial LCD (but an LVDS connection to Rpi such as this https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=157109 is possible).  The '/dev/fb'  allows single process use of an LCD using x/y graphics.  You can set individual pixels.  Qt/Gtk and others can be built for this mode.  If it is a LDC with a UART/serial interface, it will be some control language like VT100, Ansi, etc. to alter text.

If your LCD has a controller, it will be a chip on the board.  You need to determine how the LCD is connected to the RPi.  A picture of the LCD cable can be helpful.  How many lines does the flex cable have, etc.  Either find a manual, or you can use a magnifying glass to look at chip markings and then research those chips.  Serial is possible, but it could be LVDS or other methods.

You've neglected the most important detail of how this display interfaces with your board. Is it an HDMI connection (since you mention a "generic video projector")? How are you powering the display? You also seem to provide no indication that this display is functional with your board. This may not be just a software issue.
